# Angular ngOptions track by object keys

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I would like to create a select element with ngOptions – so far so good:

```
<select ng-options="currency for (code, currency) in currencies track by code"
        ng-model="something.currency"></select>
```

Now I want to track the options by the object key (so the value of the `ng-model` should be the key and not the value of the object). Is this possible in some simple way and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it what you're looking for ?

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.currencies_old = [
    {code: "USD", curr: "$"},
    {code: "IND", curr: "INR"}
  ];
  $scope.currencies = {"USD": "USDollars", "EUR": "Euro"};
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="GreetingController">
<select ng-model="item" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in currencies"></select>
Code: {{item}}
  
<br/> <br/> 
<select ng-options="item as item.curr for item in currencies_old track by item.code" ng-model="item_old"></select>
Code: {{item_old.code}}
</div>
```

Comment: No that's the "easy way". I really mean an object which is build up like `{"USD": "US Dollars", "EUR": "Euro"}`

Comment: @JSHelp : I've updated code as per your defined object. Check and let me know if you still find any problem.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Weirdly enough that's how I implemented it, only that it the `ngModel` always returned the value instead of the key but this proofs that it should work, so I will mark it as the correct solution.

Comment: @JSHelp Glad to see that it helped you :)